# How create new node and create mappings to existing node in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, py2neo, neo4j-ogm

I try to add a new node to an existing graph in neo4j, and try to create a mapping between the new node(BAI09.03) and an existing node(PR.IP-6) but am getting it like this

[image]

but my output should be like this

[image]

Comment: [Show your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong in your query :)

I suspect you do a MERGE to find your PR.IP-6 node, but you provide a property value that does not correspond, and then Neo4j will create a new node.

If you can provide the query you use, we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
CREATE (s:Sample {sampleNumber: toInteger("1234567")})
WITH s
MATCH (p:Person {personNumber: toInteger("1234")})
CREATE (p)-[:Person_Sample]->(s)
```

Suppose we have already a node in the neo4j with `personNumber: 1234`  and we are creating a new node as Sample.